# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I'm trying to use google sign in sample, but it doesn't work. I receive ApiException statusCode = 10

I use the same code like here
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

Comment: As suggested in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#inherited-method-summary), try checking the log if there are any hint of configuration issue. Also try this [Google Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start), this sample app will guide you step by step on how to implement Android sign-in properly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please add the referred code to the body of the question.

Answer (score 12):

This is two problems.
First, if you add ' .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))', you create web application Oauth2.0 in api console. try reading this 'https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start' .

Second, if you not use 'requestIdToken', you create type is android Oauth2.0.
Second does not require a clientID but  if you add code 'requestIdToken', need to add webapplication clientID.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer and solved my issue. Thanks.

Basically if you're using the Android OAuth 2.0, you shouldn't be using the requestIdToken.

Comment: Very helpful answer

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error when using the requestServerAuthCode() method?
Is there any solution to this? Because I see that it looks like a developer problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem by using SHA-256 fingerprint keys. I switched to SHA-1 and now the error is gone.